# Exchange 2010 Autodiscover returns a completely bogus server name I've never used

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-anywhere

so I have Exchange 2010 and I'm having issues with Outlook Anywhere, and when I run testconnectivity.microsoft.com, it returns:

> "The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer wasn't able to validate Outlook
>   Autodiscover settings...No account settings were returned from the
>   Autodiscover response".

So I think the problem is that my Autodiscover is faulty. This is supported by scrolling up in the results and seeing that the xml response returns an IMAP server and an SMTP server that don't exist, both called "server.myinternaldomain.com.". It literally starts with "server". Obviously, I've never called a server "server" before so I have no idea where it would get that from. It's also nowhere in my public or private DNS settings, or in any of my Exchange settings as far as I can tell. I've looked in the following places:

- Get-OutlookProvider | fl
- Get-OutlookAnywhere | fl
- Get-ClientAccessServer | fl
- Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory | fl
- Get-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory | fl
- Get-EcpVirtualDirectory | fl
- Get-OabVirtualDirectory | fl
- Get-OwaVirtualDirectory | fl
- Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory | fl

None of them show "server.myinternaldomain.com" anywhere. For the record, the mail server is called smtp.mydomain.com externally and exch.myinternaldomain.com internally.

Is there a way to change this value in the autodiscover.xml result? I've rebuilt the Autodiscover virtual directory to no avail.

**Update**: Well, I figured it out. A certificate was installed using Symantec SSL Assistant Plus. The problem was it wasn't the right certificate for the Exchange server, because it wasn't a SAN certificate. Also there already is a SAN cert installed, so a mistake all around. Compounding the issue, that utility offers to change your registry settings to harden it. Well, one of those changes broke all kinds of functionality apparently. Fortunately, the utility makes a registry backup so you can restore. After that, all was well.